# Concatenate CNN to compare two images

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I am training an CNN to compare two images. The CNN then can say if new images i put in the CNN are equal or not. Therefor i concatenate the images via cv2 so that i have images of shape (330,530,6) (in rgb) or like i would do it in grayscale (330,530,2).
This works fine for me, but i would like to know how the CNN works if i concatenate two models after flattening both of them. I'm working with the keras sequential modells. Is there a way to concatenate these two models without changing everything? Because i give the Data in the fit method i m not sure how i hand over both data to each model.

Here is the Modle i work with:

```
CNN = Sequential()
CNN.add(layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(l2Reg),input_shape=(330,530,2)))
CNN.add(layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
CNN.add(layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(l2Reg)))
CNN.add(layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3)))
CNN.add(layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(l2Reg)))
CNN.add(layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3)))
CNN.add(layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(l2Reg)))
CNN.add(layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3)))
CNN.add(layers.Flatten())
CNN.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
CNN.add(layers.Dense(128,activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(l2Reg)))
CNN.add(layers.Dense(2,activation='softmax'))
CNN.summary()
CNN.compile(optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=1e-4),loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
history=CNN.fit(XTrain,YTrain,epochs=40,batch_size=32,validation_split=0.15)
scores = CNN.evaluate(XTest,YTest,batch_size=32)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
CNN.save("AnodenerkennungDreiV")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a list of inputs, in your case with 2 items, let's say *'image1'* and *'image2'*. You can then create a branch of convolutional and pooling layers for each image that end with a *Flatten* layer.

Example with 330x530 images in grayscale:

```python
import numpy as np
from keras.utils import plot_model
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Flatten, Input, concatenate, Dense

inputs = [Input(shape=(330,530,1), name='image1'), Input(shape=(330,530,1), name='image2')]

flattened_layers = []
for input in inputs:
    conv_layer = Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu')(input)
    conv_layer = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2))(conv_layer) 
    # note that previous layer is used as input for creating the next layer,
    # you'll need to do this for every layer.

    # add more layers here
    flattened_layers.append(Flatten()(conv_layer))

output = concatenate(flattened_layers, axis=0) #you have to check which axis you want to use here
#add more layers here
output = Dense(2,activation='softmax')(output)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
plot_model(model, "C:/help_me_pls/example_model.png", show_shapes=True)
```

To feed data into this model you will need a dictionary as X values. `X['image1']` should contain all first images and `X['image2']` all second images. You should still be able to use the same y values.

Below an image showing the architecture of the example model:
[image: image of example model]

I hope I've understood your question correctly and this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the Answer. It seems that this is exactly what i want. Unfortunately my Laptop crashes if i run the Training like this, i guess thats owed by my hardware. Anyways i am not quit sure by feeding the data to the model. I have a list with 3 tensors. In the first one i have all first images, compared to your description that's image1 and the second tensor is image 2. The 3 one's are the labels. I then split them up and feed the CNN with fit([xTrain1,xTrain2],YTrain). And as well i didn't name the input as name='image1'. But i guess that shouldn't make any difference

Comment: Afaik if you indeed give as input an array of input tensors it just passes the first item of that array to the first Input, however I have always used dictionaries as input for the Fit function. I suggest you try that if just supplying an array doesn't work. And I understand you can't test my answer since your laptop crashes, or is it due to my answer?

Comment: i guess it's due to your answer and the changes i did to feed my array data to the model. Training the CNN with the concatenated images works fine with my laptop. Probably it's because i did a mistake while changing it. I try to figure it out

Comment: ok, I see. Please tell me if you found out what it was, I'm always interested to lean more.

Comment: just to let you know i made two mistakes, first of all i forgot to hand over the conv_layer to the Conv2D Layers and as well the input to the first Conv2D Layer. Second mistake was a wrong axis in the concatenate layer, i guess. Probably i have more wrong. The model learns but it is far slower that concatenate the images first and hand them to a "normal" model. But as far as i can see it everything's alright with your solution.

Comment: It may be true that a single, more complex, model is faster than multiple, simpler, models. I have used the multiple models because I was working with input of different shapes. I'll add a note to my answer that warns about using the previous layer as input for the next. It would be cool if you can mark my answer as solution. ^^

Comment: Hello, I am working on a simmilar project and was wondering how did you fix it? You mentioned that you found some errors but I just can't figure out how to resolve them.